# Xarray.DataSet from a list of Pandas.DataFrames

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-science, python-xarray

I have multiple files with bits to analyse. First i read them into a list of BitString.Bits. Then i split each file bits into the specific parts i want to see and save them into a list of Pandas.DataFrames. One DF for each file.

Now for further plotting and analysis purposes i want to store all data in one Xarray.Dataset, where i have the DataFrames stacked along the third axis with the name "dataset".

I have tried to concat each DataFrame together to an DataSet:

```
xr.concat(data_df[:], dim="dataset")
```

but i got an error saying that i cant concatenate other than DataArray or DataSets. Can i convert the DataFrames on the fly to DataArrays?

Thanks for your help!

Greetings from Germany

Jan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.to_xarray()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html) method:

```
xr.concat([df.to_xarray() for df in data_df], dim="dataset")
```

where `data_df` is a list of DataFrames

Comment: To be clear: the dim argument should be an informative name for the new dimension which distinguishes each original DataFrame from each other, so here it would be something like dim="file_bit". It has nothing to do with the fact you are concatenating them into an xarray Dataset.

Comment: I have a similar problem to this one, could you help me out with it? Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58358170/5838180